# You have a parent LWC Component A which has two child LWC components B and C. How would you communicate between B and C?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-events, parent-to-child

I was asked this question and answered as follows : I would fire a custom event from child B, I would catch the event in the handler of Parent A and retrieve the value in the handler from event.detail and set it in a property in Parent and then set it to a @api property in child C component using kebab notation.

Is this the right approach? I answered this way as I wanted to make use of Parent Child communication in LWC instead of Lightning Message Channel or Pub Sub? Or does it depend on the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Lightning Message Service or pubsub when not needed.

[image]

- Avoid using LMS or pubsub when not needed Use LMS or pubsub only when there is no common ancestor that you control

Source : - https://www.apexhours.com/design-patterns-and-best-practices-to-build-reusable-lightning-web-components/

Comment: So how should the question be answered? what if they are not in the same record page or home page?

Comment: Yes, In case there is no no common ancestor that you control then you have to use LMS or pubsub.